# How to get current selected value of drop down on OnSubmit event of AjaxUpload while ajax submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am uploading files via AjaxUpload option. I need to pass some dynamic parameters value into action. My code is as below:

```
$("#btnImportUtility_Upload").ajaxSubmit(function () {
new AjaxUpload('#btnImportUtility_Upload', {
    action: 'FileUploader.ashx?path=ExcelImportUtility&companyId=' + $("#ddlCompany option:selected").val() + '',
    name: 'upload',
    onSubmit: function (file, ext) {
        if (!(ext && /^(txt|csv|xls|xml|xlsx)$/i.test(ext))) {
            alert('Invalid File Format.');
            return false;
        }
    },
    onComplete: function (file, response) {            
    }
});
```

});

I want to get currently selected drop-down value but it always gets its initial value.

Comment: add a `console.log($("#ddlCompany option:selected").val())` before the call made.

Comment: This gives the same initial value when I put console.log inside OnSubmit event but when I put inside OnComplete event, it is giving me the currently selected value. Value is different in both events

Comment: put the `select` box html codes...

Comment: <select id="ddlCompany">
  <option value="0">A</option>
  <option value="1">B</option>
</select>

Comment: and you are getting always "0" though you are selecting 1?

Comment: Yes. I am getting always "0"

Comment: is your `#ddlCompany` is dynamic? what you get in `$(#ddlCompany).change()`?

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
$("#btnImportUtility_Upload").ajaxSubmit(function () {
new AjaxUpload('#btnImportUtility_Upload', {
action: 'FileUploader.ashx?path=ExcelImportUtility&companyId=' + $("#ddlCompany").val() + '',
name: 'upload',
onSubmit: function (file, ext) {
    if (!(ext && /^(txt|csv|xls|xml|xlsx)$/i.test(ext))) {
        alert('Invalid File Format.');
        return false;
    }
},
onComplete: function (file, response) {            
}
```

});

Comment: then check actual dropdown value in some variable like var Temp = $("#ddlCompany").val();

Comment: I also want to mention that this code is at outside from Document.ready() function, beacuse if I put this inside document.ready(), it is giving me another error.

Comment: what is the value of Temp ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
  $("#btnImportUtility_Upload").ajaxSubmit(function () {
new AjaxUpload('#btnImportUtility_Upload', {
action: 'FileUploader.ashx?path=ExcelImportUtility&companyId=' + $('#ddlCompany').val() + '',
name: 'upload',
onSubmit: function (file, ext) {
    if (!(ext && /^(txt|csv|xls|xml|xlsx)$/i.test(ext))) {
        alert('Invalid File Format.');
        return false;
    }
},
onComplete: function (file, response) {            
}
```

Your dropdown in < select> right ? please post thatone also

Comment: what is the difference between your and @Dane answer?

Comment: FYI: that doesn't make any difference to jquery.